# Session в Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, сессия

Для примера возьмем простой пример.
Юзер логиниться на сайт и хочет поменять себе ник на сайте; он заполняет форму, отправляет запрос на контроллер, ииии? Как контроллер или сервис должен знать какому именно юзеру с БД нужно изменить имя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, логин может содержаться в URL - `/users/{userName}`. Во-вторых, идентификатор пользователя может содержаться в скрытом поле формы. В обоих случаях их легко получить и извлечь из базы соответствующую сущность. Только в обоих случаях надо убедиться, что принятые логин/идентификатор соответствуют логину/идентификатору текущего пользователя.

Более элегантное и простое решение при использовании [Spring Security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) - внедрение [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html) в параметр типа [Principal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public class ProfileController {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String update(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {
      // Получаем логин текущего пользователя
      String name = principal.getName();
      return "redirect:/some-success-url";
  }
}
```

Впрочем, если такое определение метода не подходит по каким-либо причинам, `Principal` можно извлечь из [SecurityContextHolder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/profile")
public class ProfileController {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute("profile") ProfileDTO profile) {
      User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder
        .getContext()
        .getAuthentication()
        .getPrincipal();
      String name = user.getUsername();

      return "redirect:/some-success-url";
  }
}
```

**UPDATE Касательно доступа к сессии**

Сессия может быть внедрена параметром контроллера:

```
@RequestMapping("/some-url")
public void someHandler(HttpSession session, ...) {
   session.setAttribute("user", user)
}
```

или в поле:

```
@Autowired 
private HttpSession httpSession;
```

Или может быть получена из объекта [HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). Который может быть также внедрён параметром:

```
@RequestMapping("/some-url")
public void someHandler(HttpServletRequest request, ...) {
   request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
}
```

или внедрён в поле:

```
@Autowired 
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

или получен из [RequestContextHolder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html):

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
```

А ещё с объектами, сохранёнными в сессии, можно работать не используя сессию явно, с помощью аннотации контроллера `@SessionAttributes`. Корочего говоря, тысяча и один способ есть.

Comment: А можно затолкнуть юзера при входе на сайт в сессию и потом витащить, как в php: $_SESSION["user"]

Comment: Думаю, да. Но это решение того же уровня странности, как возить мешки с картошкой в феррари.

Comment: да я не такой извращенец, я на примере показал. Вопрос в том что, есть ли какой то обьект сессии с  которого можна достать разние дание? Или етот класс Principal и есть тем самим обьектом?